# What's the equivalent permission string for member user in SP 2013?

Tags: 2013, web-part, permissions, custom-permission-level, spsecurity

I have created the custom web part. this web part only needs to show the user who was in member user group.currently, i have used SharePoint trimmed control to hide the web part using permission string as **ManageWeb** permission.
but I need to give the member user need to see this web part.
what's the equivalent permission string for member user permission group?

suggest some idea.

Answer (score 6):

You can set SharePoint group as Target Audience for webpart. This way webpart will appear only to people who are members of a particular group or audience.

To do this,

1. For SharePoint 2010, 2013, and 2016, click the down arrow  Web Part edit down arrow on the right of the web part, and then click Edit Web Part.

[image]

2. In web part properties, under Advanced, add one or more audience names to the Target Audiences list.

[image]

When the page is rendered, the Web Part appears only to the people who are members of the audiences you specified.

Reference: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for the possible value of Permissions, visit this page
https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms412690

Usually the security trimming falls into these 2 types:

1. Default is hidden, show the control for users with XXX permission.
2. Default is shown, hide the control for users with XXX permission.

Which one fits your environment?